# binary tree nodes sql hackerRank question

Tags: sql, mysql, binary-tree, in-operator

I am trying to solve below question of hackerrank :
You are given a table, BST, containing two columns: N and P, where N represents the value of a node in Binary Tree, and P is the parent of N. Write a query to find the node type of Binary Tree ordered by the value of the node. Output one of the following for each node:
Root: If node is root node.
Leaf: If node is leaf node.
Inner: If node is neither root nor leaf node.

I am getting output if i use "IN" operator in second Case but not getting output if i am using "NOT IN"
could anyone please tell why it is not executing second case

```
select n,
case
when p is null then "Root"
when N  IN (select p from bst) then "Inner"
else "Leaf"
end
from bst
order by n

case
when p is null then "Root"
when N NOT IN (select p from bst) then "Leaf"
else "Inner"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using Oracle DB and Oracle uses `ANTI JOIN` for `NOT IN`.

However `NOT IN` is semantically different from the `LEFT JOIN` / `IS NULL` and `NOT EXISTS`. Since its logic is trivalent and filtering on, it will never return anything if there are `NULL` values in the list. That's why you are not getting output.

Instead you can use `EXISTS` / `NOT EXISTS` to solve it:

```sql
select N,
case
    when p is null then "Root"
    when NOT EXISTS (select p from bst b where b.p=a.n) then "Leaf"
    else "Inner"
end
from bst a
order by n;
```